# What device sizes/resolutions does Chrome's `srcset` attribute correspond to?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design, pixel-ratio

Is there a map defining what device sizes/resolutions the Google Chrome IMG `srcset` attribute sizes correspond to?

For example, in the case of

```
<img src="pic1x.png" srcset="pic1x.png 1x, pic2x.png 2x, pic4x.png 4x">
```

What size/resolution screens would receive each of those image sizes? And/or are there other sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `srcset` multiplier represents dots per pixel unit. It maps to a ratio of pixels to physical dimensions, rather than a particular resolution. Here is a simple mapping:

```
Multiplier(dppx)  Dots Per Inch(dpi)
1                 96dpi
1.3               124.8dpi
1.5               144dpi
2                 192dpi
```

```
1 dppx = 96 dpi
1 dpi = 2.54 dpcm
1 dpcm ≈ 0.39dpi
```

- dpi: dots per inch;  1dpi ≈ 2.54dpcm
- dpcm: dots per centimeter; 1dpcm ≈ 0.39dpi
- dppx: dots per px unit; 1dppx ≈ 96dpi

**References**

- [retina.js](https://github.com/imulus/retinajs/blob/master/src/retina.js)
- [Resolution Units](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/data_types/resolution)
- [What Media Queries Can My Device See](http://brettjankord.com/projects/palmreader/)
- [CSS Media Queries Implementation Report](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/MediaQueries/20120229/reports/implement-report.html)
- [The real conflict behind <picture> and @srcset](http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-real-conflict-behind-picture-and-srcset/)